# How to call a function from an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to call a function from within my directive template to convert time to something readable.  I am currently seeing `<script>document.write(convertTime({{hour.time}}));</script>` where I want to see the actual converted time.  There are no JS errors.

Directive:

```js
.directive('hourly', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="hourly_container row" ng-repeat="hour in weather.data" ng-if="(($index % 3) == 0)">' +
            '<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">Time: <script>document.write(convertTime({{hour.time}}));</script></div>' +
            '<div class="weather_block hourly col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">' +
            '<canvas id="weather_icon_{{$index}}" width="128" height="128"></canvas><br />' +
            '<span>Temp: {{hour.temperature}}  </span><br />' +
            '<span> {{hour.summary}} </span><br />' +
            '<span>Humidity: {{hour.humidity}} </span><br />' +
            '<span>Pressure: {{hour.pressure}} </span><br />' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'
    }
});
```

Function:

```js
function convertTime(time) {
    console.log("in convert time");
    var d = new Date(time * 1000);
    var hours = d.getHours()
    var minutes = d.getMinutes()

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }

    return "<span>" + d.getMonth() + " " + d.getDay() + "</span> <br />" + "<span>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</span";
}
```

I'm sure there's a right way to do this, but this isn't it.  You can see what I'm trying to do with this example though.

Comment: As a design suggestion, I would put a chunk of html that large into an Html file and use templateUrl in your directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues.  I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do with the data you are returning, but I'll let you sort that out.  I also removed some things for your directive just to get the call to the convertTime service.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/puhAkkAKTIKGZ41u3tWa?p=preview)

In order to call the function, you should put it into a service ( or factory, in this case ).  (I modified it slightly because you were doing some wrong things with your call to Date):

```
.factory('myFactory', function() {
  return {
    convertTime: function() {
    console.log("in convert time");
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = d.getHours()
    var minutes = d.getMinutes()

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours === 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }

    return "<span>" + d.getMonth() + " " + d.getDay() + "</span> <br />" + "<span>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix + "</span";
    }
  }
})
```

Then you inject the factory into the directive.

You should note also that I had to inject $sce as well, because your factory is returning a string of markup that you are intending to display.  Angular by default protects us from potentially harmful code being rendered.  If you are generating this html internally without a user being able to insert anything, then it's OK to use $sce to tell angular that we trust this bit of code.  You then need to use ng-bind-html in the div tag you want to insert that code, otherwise it renders it is plain text and not html.

```
.directive('hourly', function(myFactory, $sce) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="hourly_container row">' +
            '<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" ng-bind-html="convertTime">Time: {{convertTime}} </div>' +
            '<div class="weather_block hourly col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">' +
            '<canvas id="weather_icon_{{$index}}" width="128" height="128"></canvas><br />' +
            '<span>Temp: {{hour.temperature}}  </span><br />' +
            '<span> {{hour.summary}} </span><br />' +
            '<span>Humidity: {{hour.humidity}} </span><br />' +
            '<span>Pressure: {{hour.pressure}} </span><br />' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>',
            link: function(scope) {
              scope.hour = {
                temperature: 97,
                summary: 'some text here for the summary',
                humidity: 'Really Humid',
                pressure: -92137
              }
              scope.convertTime = $sce.trustAsHtml('Time: ' + myFactory.convertTime())
              }
       }

})
```

Comment: How do I gain access to the hour.time variable to pass to myFactory.convertTime(hour.time)?  The time I get is based out of that data object, not current time.

Comment: so just pass it into the convertTime(hour.time) function when you call it, though you need to set the factory up to use that instead of generating a new Date string.

Comment: I don't know how to access the hour.time variable.  It's not a part of scope. I do see it in $scope.$parent.hour.time, but I've tried using scope.$parent.hour.time which didn't work either.  I'm not yet fully understanding directives as a whole.

Comment: I'm able to grab my entire weather.data object, but can't then isolate to each index that represents an hour (based on the ng-repeat).

Comment: I moved the ngRepeat outside of the directive and that solved the problem (with some minor tweaks).

Comment: glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your function into a service and then you can inject the service into your directive and use the function. Something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('$utilTime', [function() {

$utilTime.convertTime = function(time) {
   //your code
  };

  return $utilTime;
}]);
```

Then inject into our directive:

```
.directive('hourly', function( $utilTime) {
```

You can then add a controller to your directive and set the value from your function to a scope variable which you can then use in your template.